# border showing left & bottom in internet explorer how to remove that borders?

Tags: css, html

```
body {
    background:#f2f3f4 url(images/ringbackbg.jpg) repeat-x;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#fff;
    font-family: MyCustomFont, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin:0;
    background-position:center 0;
    outline: none;
}
```

showing left & bottom border in internet explorer how do I remove that borders?

Comment: did ya got it resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The box model is composed of width/height, padding, border, margin, outline.

`Width`/`height` dictate the size of the box in which the content is displayed.

Paddings dictate the distance between the content and the border - background colours/images appear over the padding as well.

`Border`s go around the width/height+padding and can be styled differently. They also have a few particularities:

- they can be styled individually (top/right/bottom/left) including images;
- when declaring large borders with individual styling you will notice their corners meet diagonally;
- borders can have rounded corners;

`Margin`s go around width/height+padding+border and cannot be styled - they can only be used as spacing around the element.

`Outline`s go around the width/height+padding+border+margin and they can be styled with a few particularities of their own.

Hence using something like:

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    outline: none;
}
```

Is fairly common in any reset stylesheet.

Comment: thanks, but it didn't work i think it is default property of ie

Comment: Some things in IE are not (very) customisable (scrollbars, select boxes, image upload buttons) because they are considered to be part of the browser not part of the page (and they are supplied by the operating system). Borders and the like are customisable. Perhaps you are attempting to customise something that is indeed part of the browser window and not your HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
```

Comment: i have already try this but it only appears in ie

Comment: do you have a public link to that page?

Comment: @wintercounter backgrounds are shown over paddings so even if the `body` element had a padding, the background would have covered it. Setting the padding to 0 would only help to make sure alignments start from the same initial values.